# Simple pointer object error C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I made a small program in c++ to learn more about pointer objects. However I keep getting an error that the pointer object "bar" is not a part of the class more specifically:

> `[Error] 'class ux' has no member named 'bar'`

As shown below:

```
class ux {
private:
    int width;
    int height;

public:
    ux(int, int);
    ~ux();
    int area();
};

ux::ux(int a, int b)
{
    width = a;
    height = b;
}
ux::~ux(){}

int ux::area()
{
    return (width * height);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ux * foo;
    ux * bar;

    foo = new ux(2, 2);
    foo->bar = NULL;
    cout << foo->area() << "\n";
    cout << foo->bar << "\n";   
}
```

Why is this happening? I know it's possible to point to another pointer object with the arrow operator but it is not working here.

---------------------Update-----------------------

I am not trying to do anything with foo->bar I just want to see the address or value printed out but I know that a pointer obj can point to another pointer obj. If someone can please specify a link that shows this technique in use I would greatly appreciate that.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `foo->bar`?
In this case, `foo` is an instance of the `ux` class. `ux` doesn't have anything in it named "bar", which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: well, `ux` doesn't have a member called `bar` - so what did you expect `foo->bar` should do?

Comment: To learn about pointers, using `new` is not a requirement.  `foo ux(2, 2);  foo* fptr = &ux;`  Then practice how to use pointers using `fptr`.

Comment: I think you do not understand what `->` means. What you wrote is just "access a bar field in the object pointer by foo"...

Comment: Since `bar` is not a member of `ux`, it makes sense that the compiler does not like `foo->bar`. Remove those lines from your code.

Comment: it is hard for SO to answer your question since its not clear what you are trying to do. DO something simple first - then try to get clever. Use objects without pointers for example

Comment: to Phixle and R Sahu, I declared bar as a pointer object.

Answer (score 1):

The `->` isn't used to access arbitrary pointers, it's used to access members of the class. The members of your `ux` class are `width`, `height`, and `area`. `bar` is a completely separate variable of type `ux`, and you would use it e.g. `bar->width`, `bar->height`, or `bar->area()`.

Answer (score 0):

In line `foo->bar` you are giving an order to object `foo` to do function from class `ux` called `bar` . Your defined class `ux` does not have attribute/function defined in class. [You should read this article about operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) .Its maybe easier to learn more about C++ Classes and objects then dive into pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> I know it's possible to point to another pointer object with the arrow operator but it is not working here.

Yes it is possible. The right way to do it is:

```
foo = bar;
```

Since `foo` is a pointer, it is essentially a variable with an address as its value. To make another variable point to the same object, all you have to do is assign the address to the other variable.

As a side note, remember that every `new` should have a `delete`.